What is the forecasting approach about "weird" data
I have a hourly time series dataset consists of 4000 rows and 3 columns (they are also my target columns). What im trying to do is using XGBoost to predict future. I've used ARIMA-SARIMA-ETS but to no avail. The main problem is my data shows irregular, weird patterns that i've not seen before. It gives really high RMSE scores, MAE gives relatively better results. Below there is one of my column's STL decomposition graph.

What should i do? Differencing by d=1 ? Using a different model?

Your series does look quite irregular, there appear to be quite a few shocks which are probably the result of outside factors which you did not consider. It will be hard to model this series without this information.

Thank you for your reply. This electricity consumption data comes from water pump stations. They sometimes use it, sometimes not. As you mentioned, maybe i should try to gather exogeneous information.

Then you will probably need data about prices (or something related) which might indicate when they used pumps as it was economical to pump water.

Great point. Thank you.

As user2974951 writes, the way forward would be to understand the data generating process better. If you can understand what drives stations to pump at a specific point in time, you may be able to improve your forecasts. See How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?
Note that this knowledge must of course be available early enough. If your forecasts need to be one day ahead, then knowing that a station will start pumping five minutes before it does so will not be helpful.
Since this may well be a hurdle that will be very hard to clear, it may be useful to take a step back and determine what kind of forecast you actually need. Do you really need an hourly forecast? Will a forecast of total electricity consumption over a day be enough? Or one of the maximum consumption? Would a quantile forecast add value? Note that for all this, you need to understand what your forecasts will be used for: which decisions will be made on the basis of your forecasts?

It gives really high RMSE scores, MAE gives relatively better results.

That does not surprise me. The RMSE elicits the conditional mean, which of course depends strongly on the spikes you see, whereas the MAE elicits the conditional median, which will depend much less on those spikes. Note that especially for time series like these, the forecast that optimizes the RMSE may well be quite different from the one that minimizes the MAE, so you should really be calculating different forecasts for the two error measures - or, conversely, it does not make sense to evaluate the same forecast using different error metrics (Kolassa 2020 - ping me on ResearchGate if you are interested and do not have access).
And this underscores my point above: you need to understand which kind of forecast you need (expectation vs. some quantile like the median) and then tailor your accuracy metric to this decision, so it actually rewards what you want to elicit.

Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I forgot to mention that i need hourly forecasts because im trying to forecast 3 numeric values (active - capacitive - inductive consumption) if they will exceed some kind of threshold ( capacitive > active0.2 or inductive > active0.33). I also want to ask you if you please, that should i use MultiOutputRegressors for this kind of task? Since i'll be forecasting 3 targets. And there is actually a correlation between two targets, what kind of algorithms will take this relation into account?

OK, but of course your events do not by themselves say that you need hourly forecasts. It might make sense to do this on other granularities. And yes, it seems like a multiclass classification model might be a reasonable alternative to forecasting the numeric values. (One often finds that model combinations outperform the separate models. So you may want to do a multiclass classification with probabilistic outputs and a time series forecast with predictive densities from which you derive probabilistic predictions, then average these probabilistic predictions from the two models.)

... Unfortunately, I don't know which models would account for the correlations involved here, sorry... I recommend you look at the potential [tag:multiple-seasonalities] involved: the time of day may be important (please don't dummy-code this) but may be modulated by the day of week, especially between weekdays and weekends. Plus there may by effects of time of year.
